# CASE statement when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, kognitio, kognitio-wx2

I need some help in fixing a data aberration. I create a view based on two tables with Left Join and the result has some duplicates (as given in the logic section)

**Data Setup:**

```
*******************
       TEST1
*******************
PRODUCT VALUE1  KEY
1       2       12
1       3       13
1       4       14
1       5       15

*******************
       TEST2
*******************
KEY ATTRIBUTE
12  DESC
13  (null)
14  DESC
15  (null)
```

**What I tried so far**

```
SELECT 
    B.KEY,
    B.ATTRIBUTE,
    A.PRODUCT
    A.VALUE1
FROM TEST2 B LEFT JOIN TEST1 A ON TEST2.KEY = TEST1.KEY;
```

**What I get with above SQL is**

```
KEY ATTRIBUTE   PRODUCT VALUE1
12  DESC        1       2
13  (null)      1       3
14  DESC        1       4
15  (null)      1       5
```

**What I need to get**

```
KEY ATTRIBUTE   PRODUCT VALUE1
12  DESC        1       2
13  DESC        1       3
14  DESC        1       4
15  DESC        1       5
```

**Logic**:
Since all products with id 1 are same, I need to retain the attributes if it is NULL. So doing a distinct of PRODUCT and ATTRIBUTE will always have 1 row per product id. Test1 has more than 100 products and Test2 has corresponding descriptions.

**Note:** This is not a normalized design since it is data warehousing. So no complaints on design please

I would like to have a CASE statement in the attribute field.

```
CASE
    WHEN ATTRIBUTE IS NULL THEN {fix goes here}
    ELSE ATTRIBUTE 
END AS ATTRIBUTE
```

Some one needs to see fiddle, then go [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3d30/1/0)

Comment: Why does the attribute column of test2 contain nulls? What would be the impact of simply updating them to be the appropriate value?

Comment: Nulls are loaded from files (2 rows). Descriptions are already present in DB (2 rows). As a temporary fix, I am doing updates as you said, but I need a permanent fix in this view creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear but if you say that for each product can be only one attribute then try to use `MAX() OVER`

```
SELECT 
TEST1.Product,
TEST1.value1,
TEST2.KEY,
MAX(ATTRIBUTE) OVER (PARTITION BY test1.Product) ATTR
FROM TEST2 
  LEFT JOIN 
       TEST1 ON TEST2.KEY = TEST1.KEY
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3d30/23)</kbd>

Comment: +1 for reminding me about MAX, I will check this out. LOL over me since I suggest this to many when it comes to numbers and I forgot trying it for char/varchar

Comment: You nailed it. :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3d30/45/0):

```
SELECT B.KEY,
  CASE WHEN B.ATTRIBUTE IS NULL THEN 
  (
    SELECT s2.ATTRIBUTE
    FROM test2 s2
    LEFT JOIN TEST1 s1 ON s1.KEY = s2.KEY
    WHERE s1.PRODUCT = A.PRODUCT
    AND s2.ATTRIBUTE IS NOT NULL
    AND ROWNUM = 1
  ) ELSE B.ATTRIBUTE END AS ATTRIBUTE, 
  A.PRODUCT, A.VALUE1
FROM TEST2 B 
LEFT JOIN TEST1 A ON A.KEY = B.KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
NVL(attribute,'DESC')
FROM TEST2 LEFT JOIN TEST1 ON TEST2.KEY = TEST1.KEY;
```

Just seen its Oracle please try above

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this is a bad suggestion you can make. Also in future if you want to do a NULL Check and replace then go for NVL or COALESCE